# Applying for a visitor visa to Australia from New Zealand. Is medical exam required for a 3 day stay?

Tags: visas, australia, chinese-citizens

I am flying to Melbourne in July for a 2 day conference and want to take my spouse with me.  I'm a NZ citizen from birth.

However, she is still on a working visa with multiple re-entry rights to NZ and a PRC passport.

I gather the processing time for visas is 30 working days.  And since she is applying from NZ, she needs to travel to Auckland so that her biometrics can be captured.

I'm unclear as to whether she also needs a medical examination.  It seems they're asking about polio vaccination status, and proof of no active tuberculosis.  Seems a bit excessive since we'll be in the country the same time as a transit visa (72 hours), but the latter doesn't allow one to leave the airport from my reading of their extremely circular referencing site.  So, I can't apply for a transit visa for her.  And instead I need a visitor/business visa.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about australia but generally transit visas require you to actually be in transit to a third country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a short term visit of less than six months, [Australia does not usually require medical examinations, except under certain circumstances](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations).

In addition, there are special circumstances surrounding [particular threats to public health](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations), such as tuberculosis, HIV, yellow fever, polio, and Ebola.

In particular, the following are said about tuberculosis and polio:

> If you are applying for a temporary visa you may be asked to undergo tuberculosis testing on a risk management basis.
>
> Applicants will be asked to provide a polio vaccination certificate if applying for a visa from outside of Australia if:
>
> - you have spent 28 days or longer in Afghanistan, Cameroon, Equatorial Guinea, Ethiopia, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia or Syria, or in any combination of these countries, on or after 5 May 2014

Was it clear on your visa application that you would only be there for three days?

Comment: I searched for a couple of days and couldn't find out how to actually apply for a visa! I think we have to travel to Auckland to do this in person at their representative's facility there. I'm traveflling to a medical conference which might be held at a hospital.  My interpretation of this page  http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations is that if my wife meets me in the hospital cafeteria to have lunch, she will need a CXR and a medical examination.

Comment: Yes, I strongly suspect that the hospital venue is why they're asking for the medical exam and all the rest.